# How do I force a Multipass VM to refresh it's IP and obtain a completely new one

Tags: multipass

I need to force a multipass VM to change it's IP address.
It can't use the same one as I'm trying to debug an issue where the IP changes.

I have tried several things but none were successful.  Any ideas?